# How can I save 'favicon.ico' in radiant

Tags: radiant

I have not found a specific area to save the `favicon.ico` so I sending him to the area of assets.
But I can not get it back again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is in fact not related to Radiant at all.
As with any Rails application, you should just put your favicon.ico in the public/ folder.

Update: Ok.. if you múst use the backend to set the favicon, you could just do this in your layout:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="<r:asset id="your asset's id"><r:link/></r:asset>" type="image/x-icon" />
```

.. or just 'hard code' the path to the asset you uploaded:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/assets/your asset's id/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but the radiant not have a way to change the favicon for the interface? Some users do not have ssh access.